# which is the best way to work RAILS with Hbase?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hbase, stargate

Already install https://github.com/greglu/hbase-stargate
, but it seems, that some methods is not working appropriate, 
for example:  `row = @client.create_row('terms', 'book', Time.now.to_i, {:name => 'data:fr', :value => 2})`

In Hbase shell I got empty value:

```
 scan 'terms',  {CACHE_BLOCKS => false} ROW  COLUMN+CELL  book  column=data:fr, timestamp=1325880415, value=
```

Also, some rows does not created at all. 
This is my schema for table:

```
table_options = { :name => 'data', \
    :max_versions => 1, \
    :compression => Stargate::Model::CompressionType::NONE, \
    :in_memory => false, \
    :block_cache => false, \
    :ttl => -1, \
    :max_cell_size => 2147483647
    }
    client.create_table('terms', table_options)
```

Whats wrong with hbase-stargate gem?

Which is the best way(fastest) to integrate rails with hbase? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [massive_record](https://github.com/CompanyBook/massive_record/) might be a better option.